# Error:Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: ionic2, custom-component

I am new to ionic 2,by following this tutorial https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/  i wanted to display the Expandable header component. Here i created the custom component naming `ionic g component ExpandableHeader` when i import it in `app.module.ts`.

Below is my `app.module.ts` code:

```
import { ExpandableHeader } from '../components/expandable-
        header/expandable-header';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 MyApp,
 HomePage,
 ExpandableHeader
],
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
 MyApp,
 HomePage
],
 providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
 })
export class AppModule {}
```

When i try to import it shows the error.How can i solve this error

Comment: I get this error as well but randomly. I am using Ionic 3.0.1. I need to restart ionic serve to get rid of it.

Comment: Restarting Ionic Serve worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `providers: [StatusBar,SplashScreen,ErrorHandler]`

and Try to define `provide:` and `useClass` in your  page constructor.

Comment: I had tried previously what you said but getting same error

Comment: Ok check the expandable header path is true or false if it's true try remove statusbar and splashscreen...